# Distinct permutations of a string modulo a prime

Tags: algorithm, math

I thought of the following problem recently, and I'm quite surprised that there doesn't seem to be anybody who asked this question yet:

Given a string, how many distinct permutations of it exist, modulo [image: 1000000007]?

I know the formula [image: formula] where [image: N] is the length of the string, and [image: A1A2AK] are the count of each character (considering an alphabet of size [image: K]). So, the string `toffee` would have [image: 180] different permutations.

But this doesn't quite work anymore when [image: N] can be really large (say [image: 100000]), since computing [image: Nfactorial] would go out of the range of *long long int*, and using BigIntegers would be too slow. Is there any way to compute this in, say, [image: N] or [image: NlogN] time?

If I preprocessed the factorials from [image: 1] to [image: N], and my "strings" came in the form of an array of length [image: K] where each element contained the count of each letter, would it be possible to compute it in [image: K] or [image: KlogK] time?

Would appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to note that `p = 10^9 + 7` is a prime number. Therefore, we can use multiplicative inverses and [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to turn the divisions in your formula into multiplications by the inverses:

```
n! / (a1!*...*ak!) = 

n! * a1!^(p - 2) * ... * ak!^(p - 2) (mod p)
```

Which will be your formula mod `p` with no divisions and an easy implementation (just use modular [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)).

Complexity will be `O(k log p + n)`, since we have `O(k)` multiplications, and for each one, an `O(log p)` exponentiation, and we must also compute `n!` and the factorial of each count.

This is easier to implement than cancelling out factors in the fraction.

Comment: Is it `n! * a1^(p - 2) * ... * ak^(p - 2) (mod p)` or `n! * (a1!)^(p - 2) * ... * (ak!)^(p - 2) (mod p)`?

Comment: @RobinYu you're right, you must take the factorials. You can take them modulo `p` and then exponentiate that.

Comment: (y) This answer deserves more votes than it had so far.

Comment: Beautiful answer, Vlad, thanks for sharing. Ai cele mai utile raspunsuri de teoria numerelor :)

Answer (score 2):

The number of distinct permutations of a string is always an integer, despite being the result of a division. That's because the factors of the denominator essentially "knock out" some of the factors of the numerator. So you can eliminate the division as a post-factorial operation, instead dividing out the particular factors of the factorial which you've matched up with factors of the denominator.

Once you've got the division removed, you're just left with modular multiplication, which is simple.

Answer (score 0):

If `N` isn't gigantic (that is, it's small enough to sift it using something like Sieve of Eratosthenes), you can calculate the prime factorisation of `N!` with a modified version of the sieve.

Then you can use the prime factorisation to calculate the division, cancelling out the factors present on both sides of the division.

Though this doesn't take into account the fact that you want the result modulo a prime number (where better solutions exist), it's probably useful to know in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. a solution exists. You can read about Modular multiplicative inverse algorithm. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

As the answer is with modulo 1000000007(which is a prime also), you can try [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to solve this problem. If modulo number is ***mod*** Complexity is O(N + K * log(mod)).

Comment: The complexity is not `O(n log n)`.